# Reuse of service-activator for several gateway methods with Splitter

Tags: spring-integration

does somebody happen to know if it is valid to reuse a service activator and so also the output-channel using several methods (inbound) especially with a splitter and aggregator.

--> Always with result on the gateway.

In several tests it seems to work fine. As soon I added a splitter with an aggregator I get wrongs result routed to the gateway which then fails with a conversion exception (here in my case it cannot convert boolean to integer).

Thanks,

Paul

## Flow

[image: Spring Integration Flow]

## Spring Integration Config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd">

    <int:gateway service-interface="activity.BulbMessageGateway">
        <int:method name="sendToBulb" request-channel="bulbMessages" reply-channel="bulbSendResult"></int:method>
        <int:method name="updateHomeLightStatus" request-channel="homeBulbEntity" reply-channel="homeBulbEntityResult">
        </int:method>
        <int:method name="updateLightStatus" request-channel="bulbEntities" reply-channel="bulbSendResult">
            <int:header name="homeId" expression="#args[0].homeId"/>
            <int:header name="bulbId" expression="#args[0].strongId"/>
        </int:method>
    </int:gateway>

    <int:channel id="bulbMessages" />
    <int:channel id="bulbSendResult" />
    <int:channel id="bulbEntities" />

    <int:channel id="homeBulbEntity" />
    <int:channel id="homeBulbEntityResult" />

    <int:chain input-channel="homeBulbEntity" output-channel="bulbEntities">
        <int:splitter expression="payload.bulbs" />
        <int:header-enricher>
            <int:header name="bulbId" expression="payload.strongId"/>
            <int:header name="homeId" expression="payload.homeId"/>
        </int:header-enricher>
    </int:chain>

    <int:transformer method="bulbToLightStatus" input-channel="bulbEntities" output-channel="bulbMessages">
        <bean class="util.BulbTransformer"></bean>
    </int:transformer>

    <int:aggregator input-channel="bulbSendResult" output-channel="homeBulbEntityResult" method="aggregate">
        <bean class="util.BooleanAggregator" />
    </int:aggregator>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="bulbMessages" output-channel="bulbSendResult" method="send">
        <bean class="activity.BulbWebsocketMessageSenderBA" />
    </int:service-activator>
</beans>
```

## Unit test

```
@Test
public void sendMessageNoReceiver() {
    assertFalse(gateway.sendToBulb(new HomeId("1"), new BulbId("1"), BulbMessageBuilder.restart("foo")));
}

@Test
public void sendMessageWithReceiver() {
    MockSession<BulbId, BulbBE> bulbSession = new MockSession<BulbId, BulbBE>(new BulbBE(HomeId.of("1"), BulbId.of("1"), "bulb", "pass"));
    registry.addBulbSession(bulbSession);
    assertTrue(gateway.sendToBulb(new HomeId("1"), new BulbId("1"), BulbMessageBuilder.restart("foo")));
    assertEquals(1, bulbSession.receivedMessages());
}

@Test
public void updateBulbStatus() {
    final MockSession<BulbId, BulbBE> bulbSession1 = new MockSession<BulbId, BulbBE>(new BulbBE(HomeId.of("1"), BulbId.of("1"), "bulb", "pass"));
    assertFalse(gateway.updateLightStatus(bulbSession1.getIdentity()));

    registry.addBulbSession(bulbSession1);
    assertTrue(gateway.updateLightStatus(bulbSession1.getIdentity()));
    assertEquals(1, bulbSession1.receivedMessages());

    final MockSession<BulbId, BulbBE> bulbSession2 = new MockSession<BulbId, BulbBE>(new BulbBE(HomeId.of("1"), BulbId.of("2"), "bulb", "pass"));
    assertFalse(gateway.updateLightStatus(bulbSession2.getIdentity()));

    registry.addBulbSession(bulbSession2);
    assertTrue(gateway.updateLightStatus(bulbSession2.getIdentity()));
    assertTrue(gateway.updateLightStatus(bulbSession2.getIdentity()));

    assertEquals(2, bulbSession2.receivedMessages());
    assertEquals(1, bulbSession1.receivedMessages());
}
@Test
public void updateHomeBulbStatus() {
    final HomeBE home = new HomeBE();
    home.setId(new ObjectId());

    final MockSession<BulbId, BulbBE> bulbSession1 = new MockSession<BulbId, BulbBE>(new BulbBE(home.getStrongId(), BulbId.of("1"), "bulb", "pass"));
    registry.addBulbSession(bulbSession1);
    final MockSession<BulbId, BulbBE> bulbSession2 = new MockSession<BulbId, BulbBE>(new BulbBE(home.getStrongId(), BulbId.of("2"), "bulb", "pass"));
    registry.addBulbSession(bulbSession2);

    home.addBulb(bulbSession1.getIdentity());

    assertEquals(1, gateway.updateHomeLightStatus(home));
    assertEquals(1, bulbSession1.receivedMessages());
    assertEquals(0, bulbSession2.receivedMessages());

    home.addBulb(bulbSession2.getIdentity());
    assertEquals(2, gateway.updateHomeLightStatus(home));
    assertEquals(2, bulbSession1.receivedMessages());
    assertEquals(1, bulbSession2.receivedMessages());
}
```

The last test fails if it is executed together with the other tests. It passes if it is executed alone.

The error is that the last method (using the splitter) receives now a boolean, which seems to be a result of the other two methods registered. The result of these methods is a boolean.

Comment: - BooleanAggregator counts true values
- BulbTransformer does the conversion to the type the service expects in the activator
* Method: sendToBulb sends just the message as is
* Method: updateLightStatus sends the message but just converts once
* Method: updateHomeLightStatus sends now a collection which is part of the given argument extracted using a splitter expression *payload.bulbs*

Comment: Move this to your question as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please, share config on the matter.

And according your graph it would be better if you'd minimize the config as much as possible to isolate the problem.

From other side, please, be more specific: your question is fully unclear.

That is your own *service*. How can we be sure that it is safe to be used in different places? Only you, as an author, can determine that.

**UPDATE**

Sorry for the delay. Was busy with the release.

And thank for sharing the config for your use-case.

Now I see the problem.

You use everywhere on the gateway's methods a `reply-channel`. See the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway-default-reply-channel) on the matter when you need that:

> Typically you don’t have to specify the default-reply-channel, since a Gateway will auto-create a temporary, anonymous reply channel, where it will listen for the reply. However, there are some cases which may prompt you to define a default-reply-channel (or reply-channel with adapter gateways such as HTTP, JMS, etc.).

Since you use the same `bulbSendResult` in different places the behavior is really unpredictable. Moreoever that channel is `DirectChannel`, so the `round-robin` balancer are on the scene.

You should get rid of those `reply-channel`'s at all and just rely from your downstream components on the `replyChannel` header. Therefore you should remove those `output-channel`s in the components which are intended to return replies to your gateway.

For example the last `service-activator` should be just like this:

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="bulbMessages" method="send">
    <bean class="activity.BulbWebsocketMessageSenderBA"/>
</int:service-activator>
```

Since you general question how to reuse this `service-activator`, I'm answering to the question having the config from you:

```
<int:chain input-channel="homeBulbEntity">
    <int:splitter expression="payload.bulbs"/>
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="bulbId" expression="payload.strongId"/>
        <int:header name="homeId" expression="payload.homeId"/>
    </int:header-enricher>
    <int:transformer method="bulbToLightStatus">
        <bean class="util.BulbTransformer"/>
    </int:transformer>
    <int:gateway request-channel="bulbMessages"/>
    <int:aggregator method="aggregate">
        <bean class="util.BooleanAggregator"/>
    </int:aggregator>
</int:chain>
```

Pay attention to the absent `output-channel` for the `<chain>`. Therefore it sends reply directly to the `replyChannel` from headers and as a `return` to your `updateHomeLightStatus` gateway's method.

Another trick is that `<int:gateway request-channel="bulbMessages"/>` which sends messages in the middle of the `<chain>` flow to your `<service-activator>` and wait for the reply from there exactly the same way as a top-level gateway - via `replyChannel` header.  For the `<service-activator>` without an `output-channel` it is a black-box where to send the reply. It uses just `replyChannel` from headers!

After receiving the reply `gateway` in the `<chain>` push the message to the `<aggregator>`.

When `aggregator` will do its logic, the result will be send to the top-level gateway as an output from the `<chain>`.

That's all.

Let me know what else isn't clear here.

Comment: added xml configuration and test, hope it helps

Comment: Sorry for delay anyway, but, please, find an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot Artem! This really helps. Just by reading it I already see what I did wrong. Cool trick with the <int:gateway -- this is really a nice trick. I will keep you posted as soon I get time to apply it. Just got dragged away a bit.